# Javascript. Filter data

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a stupid question. 
I need to filter data from variable.
I have a var a:

```
var a = "Name: Kevin, DoB: 16 May 1987, Hobby: Bikes"
```

Now i want to assign to var B the result from var a but only DoB.
The result must be:

```
var b = "16 May 1987"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).  This will help you get started:

```
var b = a.match( /DoB:\s*([^,]+),/)[1]
```

Matches one or more characters after `DOB:\s*` - in other words, `DOB:` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7d3x/